# Apache "filesmatch" directive in htaccess not matching as expected

Tags: .htaccess

I have a filesmatch directive in my .htaccess file:

```
<filesMatch "admin">
    AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Area"
    require valid-user
</filesMatch>
```

It matches http://www.website.com/admin (and sub-pages such as /admin/edit_page)

But not http://www.website.com/index.php/admin

(I also have a mod_rewrite rule to hide the index.php from most of the website, don't know if this conflicts).

The mod rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 #Removes access to the system folder by users.
 #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
 #previously this would not have been possible.
 #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
 #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
 #request to index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the mod_rewrite rule as well; it's impossible to see any conflicts otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

FilesMatch matches *physical filesystem objects*. index.php/admin is not one of those.

Comment: Is there a directive which _would_ match a generic "admin" path?

Comment: Well caught! I've not tried it, but LocationMatch might work.